# Is it possible to use Verilog generate statement to manipulate signal name?

Tags: verilog

I have a `` `define `` macro that takes a 1-D signal as input.

```
`define FOO(x,width) \
reg [width-1:0] total_``x; \
always@(posedge clk) begin \
   if (rst) total_``x = 'h0; \
   else     total_``x = total_``x + ``x; \
end
```

I have a 2-D signal

```
reg [7:0] signal_2d [127:0];
```

I would like to do the following in generate for statement :

```
generate
 for (genvar i=0; i<128; i=i+1) begin
     `FOO(signal_2d[i],8);
 end
endgenerate
```

But it won't work since signal_2d is a packed array.
Is expanding the 2-D array into 128 1-D-unpacked signals an option?

How could I use generate for loop to manipulate signal name depending on for loop index.
For example, creating signal_2d_"index" ?

```
reg [7:0] signal_2d_0;
reg [7:0] signal_2d_1;
reg [7:0] signal_2d_2;
....
reg [7:0] signal_2d_127;
```

Answer (score 1):

`` `define `` macro will resolve before generate block, so adding an extra input for `i` to the macro will not help. Macros are very challenging to debug too. I'd suggest getting rid of the macro and use the sub scopes created by the generate loop to manage the name conflict. (Note: you should use non-blocking (`<=`) when assigning flops)

```
genvar i;
generate
  for (i=0; i<128; i=i+1) begin : my_label
    reg [width-1:0] total_signal;
    always@(posedge clk) begin
      if (rst) total_signal <= 'h0;
      else     total_signal <= total_signal + signal_2d[i];
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

`total_signal_2d_0` will exist as `my_lable[0].total_signal` and `total_signal_2d_127` will exist as `my_lable[127].total_signal`

Alternatively, you could keep total as a 2D array and move the for-loop inside the always block:

```
reg [7:0] signal_2d [127:0];
reg [7:0] total [127:0];
integer i;
always@(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) for(i=0;i<128;i=i+1) total[i] <= 'h0;
  else     for(i=0;i<128;i=i+1) total[i] <= total[i] + signal_2d[i];
```

SystemVerilog

```
logic [7:0] signal_2d [128];
logic [7:0] total [128];
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) total[i] <= '{ default:'0 };
  else     foreach(signal_2d[i]) total[i] <= total[i] + signal_2d[i];
```